# Smart Contract Upgradeability in Avalanche Protocol

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, avalanche

Is it possible to make smart contracts upgradeable on Avalanche protocol. Does it follow the same architecture as in Ethereum. Request for guidance in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Avalanche supports upgradeable smart contracts just like Ethereum / Binance Smart Chain do. You should use proxy contract for this.